# Looking For Ansible Module

Tags: ansible

we have a situation where we need to compare the two versions in a specific path and we need to change the symlink and point to the greater version.

ex:path=/apps/share

ls -lrt

8.5.38

8.5.39

current --> 8.5.39

I need to compare the above two versions and I need to point the symlink to the greater version. My question do we have a module in Ansible that compares between two versions

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does have a [version compare](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) test. You would use it something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "version is newer"
  when: new_version is version(old_version, '>')
```

You would of course need to extract the version information from your paths so that you can use it in the conditional.